# PHP MYSQLI not installed? error 500

Tags: php, mysqli

I have recently setup a virtual box with ubuntu and I'm trying to connect PHP to my database but it's not.
this is the error which I get in the logs.

> [:error] [pid 13614] [client 192.168.1.21:58944] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Class     'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/test/index.php on line 7

I have searched for a fix for ages but I can't find any which works

I also tried it with PDO says i don't have drivers.
https://gyazo.com/d18c383fa58565ed0710fa2506b15ebd

Comment: Can you connect to your database from the mysql command line interface?

Comment: @MarkMiller it says class mysqli not found, i think mysqli extension is not installed on his end

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php check this

Comment: I'm a bit new to linux etc, could you tell me how to connect via the command line interface? @MarkMiller

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I saw that but I have no idea what to do with that.

Comment: mysql -u <your database user name> -p

Comment: `mysql -u USERNAME -p` then the you'll be prompted for the password.

Comment: are you using any virtual server?

Comment: You'll be asked for the password after that.

Comment: What version of PHP do you have?

Comment: @MarkMiller https://gyazo.com/f8db02d4709df0deb34be5fce34ede26

Comment: @chris85 https://gyazo.com/90a83bdc7a9b3620626c218078e9f1f2

Comment: I think this is going to end up turning into a chat.  @JordDuineveld, good, you've shown that your mysql server and client work, and that you know a valid username and password.  The comments about the mysqli libraries not being installed seem on target.  Your PHP sure is old.  Version 7.x is current.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I'm using a virtual box

Comment: @MarkMiller How do I install it then? I uncommented the thing in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli code is supposed to be included in the appropriate php/mysql system package.  I have an Ubuntu server with php 7.0 and MySQL, but I couldn't establish a mysqli connection, either.

> For you, I would start with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`
>
> ***BTW, is your Ubuntu even a recent release?***  Maybe that's a better route here:  start with a recent installer or VB image.

On my otherwise up-to-date system, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

and now I can run

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", <USER>, <PASSWORD>, <DATABASE>);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", <USER>, <PASSWORD>, <DATABASE>, 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

(From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled ubuntu and now it works fine.